# How do I complete an app.post that grabs the LAST_INSERT_ID and runs a second app.post using that last inserted id?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, mariadb

This is what my code looks like:

```
var first_name;
var last_name;
var email;
var id;
var obj;

//User register post
app.post('/user-register', registerCheck, (req, res, next) => {

    first_name = req.body.first_name;
    last_name = req.body.last_name;
    email = req.body.email;

    obj = {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email
    }

    req.session["user"] = obj;

    var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles (First_Name, Last_Name, Email)
        SELECT ?, ?, ? 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles WHERE Email = ?);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;

    pool.query(sql, [first_name, last_name, email, email], (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    .then(rows => {
        id = rows[0].insertId;
        //console.log(id);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    next();
});

app.post('/user-register', (req, res) => {

    var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles_IP (Student_id, IP_1, IP_2, IP_3, IP_4)
    SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles_IP WHERE Student_id = ?)`;

    pool.query(sql, [id, ip_1, ip_2, ip_3, ip_4, id], (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    .then(rows => {
        console.log(rows);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

I need to grab the id(LAST_INSERT_ID) and then run the next app.post so I can use the id in the next app.post query.

I tried using next(), but by the time the second app.post run, the id equals undefined. It looks like the code runs through everything and then grabs the id at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Attach your variable to the req object:

```
pool.query(sql, [first_name, last_name, email, email], (err, data) => 
{
    if (err) throw err;
})
.then(rows => 
{
    id = rows[0].insertId;
    req.lastid=id;
    next();
})
.catch(err => 
{
    console.log(err);
});
```

And in other request you can catch it like this:

```
app.post('/user-register', (req, res) => {
let lastid=req.lastid;
var sql = `INSERT INTO Govt_profiles_IP (Student_id, IP_1, IP_2, IP_3, IP_4)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Govt_profiles_IP WHERE Student_id = ?)`;

pool.query(sql, [id, ip_1, ip_2, ip_3, ip_4, id], (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
.then(rows => {
    console.log(rows);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
})
```